# How to update the specific value in JSON and store it back in variable using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm reading JSON from file and would like to update the `produtCost` from 1200 to 1500 and store it back in variable. Instead of updating existing `productCost` - its adding new field `produtCost` at the end.  Please find my code below - how to fix this? Any help would be much appreciated.

**input.json**

```
[
    {
        "productName": "Apple",
        "produtCost": "1200",
        "details": {
            "description": "test"
        },
        "extension": {
            "type": "electroincs",
            "manifest": {
                "claims": "a",
                "parent": "none"
            }
        },
        "status": "success"
    }
]
```

**product.js**

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const fileName = './input.json';
const product = require(fileName);

product.produtCost = "1500";
console.log(file);
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    {
        "productName": "Apple",
        "produtCost": "1500",
        "details": {
            "description": "test"
        },
        "extension": {
            "type": "electroincs",
            "manifest": {
                "claims": "a",
                "parent": "none"
            }
        },
        "status": "success"
    }
]
```

Comment: `product[0].produtCost = "1500";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`product` is an array so you have to first access its elements through `index` and then change the property of an object

```
product[0].produtCost = "1500";
```

```js
const product = [{
  productName: "Apple",
  produtCost: "1200",
  details: {
    description: "test",
  },
  extension: {
    type: "electroincs",
    manifest: {
      claims: "a",
      parent: "none",
    },
  },
  status: "success",
}, ];

product[0].produtCost = "1500";
console.log(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo on the json, putting     "produtCost" instead of productCost

You can also return a new object instead of modifying the actual one by using the [spread operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/redux/use-the-spread-operator-on-arrays) ...

example

```
let newObject={...product[0]}
newObject.productCost="1500"
console.log(product) //this will log original product
console.log(newObject)//this will log product with new productCost
```

Comment: How can you spread an array inside an object. `product` is an array. It should be `[...product]` and then you have to find out that particular object whose `productName` is `apple` and then reassign a new value to it. or it should be `{ ...product[0] }`

Comment: okay, answer updated. I did not notice it could be an array of multiple products